# Save data from firebase real time database to android local database (SQLite)

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-connection, mobile-application

I wanted to save all my data from firebase database into a local database in (JSON format only)  for my application to access it when not connected to internet. It consists even images in it along with string form of data.

Firebase allots very less space for offline mode saving data into the application hence can't use it.

I want data to be first saved in my local database and then to be retrieved into the recyclerView of my application.

Moreover I want to save login details as well as other user specific details required to keep the application function without internet into particular user's login.

Searched for answers but no reliable or step by step guide I encountered.

Are these things possible?  What should I do  ? Please guide.